# EF Core - Expression Tree Equivalent for IQueryable Search

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an initial workflow put together that allows me to perform inclusive searches for string properties of objects contained in an `IQueryable`:

```cs
public static IQueryable ApplySearch(this IQueryable queryable, string search)
{
    // validation omitted for brevity
    var expression = queryable
        .Cast<object>()
        .Where(item => item.SearchStringTree(search))
        .Expression;

    var result = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
    return result;
}

static bool SearchStringTree<T>(this T value, string search) =>
    value.GetObjectStrings().Any(s => s.Contains(search.ToLower()));

static IEnumerable<string> GetObjectStrings<T>(this T value)
{
    var strings = new List<string>();

    var properties = value.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.CanRead);

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var t = prop.PropertyType.ToString().ToLower();
        var root = t.Split('.')[0];

        if (t == "system.string")
        {
            strings.Add(((string)prop.GetValue(value)).ToLower());
        }
        else if (!(root == "system"))
        {
            strings.AddRange(prop.GetValue(value).GetObjectStrings());
        }
    }

    return strings;
}
```

Would it be possible to apply this concept in a way that Entity Framework can translate prior to DbContext execution?

I've been looking into potentially using [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries) to accomplish this.

Here's a working [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@JaimeStill/IQueryableSearch) showing the `IQueryable` implementation above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need to build expression tree, basically multi `or` (C# `||`) predicate expression for all (nested) `string` properties.

Something like this (expression version of your code):

```
public static class FilterExpression
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplySearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string search)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search)) return source;

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        // The following simulates closure to let EF Core create parameter rather than constant value (in case you use `Expresssion.Constant(search)`)
        var value = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(new { search }), nameof(search));
        var body = SearchStrings(parameter, value);
        if (body == null) return source;

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }

    static Expression SearchStrings(Expression target, Expression search)
    {
        Expression result = null;

        var properties = target.Type
          .GetProperties()
          .Where(x => x.CanRead);

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            Expression condition = null;
            var propValue = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(target, prop);
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var comparand = Expression.Call(propValue, nameof(string.ToLower), Type.EmptyTypes);
                condition = Expression.Call(comparand, nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes, search);
            }
            else if (!prop.PropertyType.Namespace.StartsWith("System."))
            {
                condition = SearchStrings(propValue, search);
            }
            if (condition != null)
                result = result == null ? condition : Expression.OrElse(result, condition);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

The non generic version is not much different - just instead of `Where` extension method you need to generate a "call" to it in the query expression tree:

```
public static IQueryable ApplySearch(this IQueryable source, string search)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search)) return source;

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "e");
    var value = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(new { search }), nameof(search));
    var body = SearchStrings(parameter, value);
    if (body == null) return source;

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
    var filtered = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Where), new[] { source.ElementType },
        source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(filtered);
}
```

While this works, it's not much useful because all LINQ extensions methods (including `AsEnumerable(),`ToList()` etc.) work with generic interface.

Also in both cases, the type of the query element must be known in advance, e.g. `T` in the generic version, `query.ElementType` in the non generic version. This is because expression tree are processed in advance, when there are no "objects", hence it can't use `item.GetType()`. For the same reason, `IQueryable` translators like EF Core don't like `Cast` "calls" inside the query expression tree.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Would this work with Entity Framework Core? When I run the example from the question prior to loading the `IQueryable` data into memory, an exception is thrown that basically says that EF cannot translate the logic into SQL.

The big reason I want it to execute prior to querying data from `DbContext` is that I want it to work hand in hand with pagination and sorting.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you made `ApplySearch` generic, but I'm working with a standard `IQueryable` without type information (hence all the reflection).

Comment: (1) Yes, this aproach allows EF Core query translation (2) I noticed that you use non generic `IQueryable`, but found it kind of strange, especially with `Cast<object>` before and `Cast<Item>` after. Note that such `Cast` calls are not supported by EF Core. And most of the time you have the typed `IQueryable` as with standard LINQ. Anyway, if you really want `ApplySearch` to use non generic `IQueryable`, the modification is relatively simple because the main work is in the private recursive method which find string properties and builds expressions.

Comment: The reason the non generic `IQueryable` is used is because the source is retrieved from `ResultExecutingContext.Result.Value` in the `ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecutionAsync` method.

Thanks again for your help. Expression Tree syntax is kind of intimidating compared to writing LINQ queries, but this is definitely enough to get me where I need to be.